# c# use of unassigned local variable after Try..Catch

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I am using the below code to get a running instance of MS Word.

I now have a compile problem with 'Use of unassigned local variable "oWord"'

here is my code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord ; 

try
{
// Is Word running?
oWord = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application; // ApplicationClass;
}
catch (COMException ce)
{
if (ce.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)0x800401E3))
    // No, Word not in ROT, start a new instance
    oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
}
// Use instance referened by _WordApp 

oWord.ScreenUpdating = false; // < PROBLEM HERE

object objDefaultBehaviorWord8 = WdDefaultTableBehavior.wdWord8TableBehavior;
object objAutoFitFixed = WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitFixed;

//MAKING THE APPLICATION VISIBLE
oWord.Visible = Properties.Settings.Default.DebugMode;
oWord.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
```

but to my mind oWord **is** assigned, I'm guessing that the the compiler is looking at my Try..Catch block and saying I have unassigned **oWord**

So what's the correct way to assign this?

Comment: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord = null`

Comment: What value does `oWord` have when the `if` evaluates to false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord; 
try
{
    oWord = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") as
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application;
}
catch (COMException ce)
{
    if (ce.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)0x800401E3))
        oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
}
oWord.ScreenUpdating = false;
```

Let's try to see why the compiler tells you that `oWord` may not be assigned after this code has executed.

1. If the code inside the `try` executes without exception, then `oWord` must be assigned.
2. Or, if that code throws an exception it may be unhandled, in which case it propagates beyond the code above.
3. Or, if the code in the try throws `COMException` it will be caught. If the error code is `0x800401E31` then `oWord` is assigned.
4. Or, if the error code is other than `0x800401E3`, then `oWord` is never assigned.

We can annotate your code to demonstrate this more clearly:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord; 
try
{
    oWord = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") as
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application;
}
catch (COMException ce)
{
    // oWord still not initialized ....
    if (ce.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)0x800401E3))
        oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    else
        ; // .... and still not initialized ....
}
oWord.ScreenUpdating = false;
```

---

The simplest way to deal with this, in my view, is to re-throw the exception.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord; 
try
{
    oWord = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") as
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application;
}
catch (COMException ce)
{
    if (ce.ErrorCode != unchecked((int)0x800401E3))
        throw;
    oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
}
oWord.ScreenUpdating = false;
```

This avoids the need to initialiaze the variable to `null` and later test for it still being `null`.

What's more it explicitly deals with the error condition that your code fails to handle. Namely a COM error other than `MK_E_UNAVAILABLE`.

Comment: @DavidHefferman: Thanks for such a completely informative and helpful answer... I just learnt something!

Answer (score 6):

It might never get assigned if the `Marshal.GetActiveObject` call fails, but the error code is something other than `unchecked((int)0x800401E3)`.

You need to set `oWord` to something when you first declare it:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord = null;
```

or

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

I'd probably do the latter. That also removes the need for null checks further down the line, which right now you really should have since you're not fully aborting if there's an exception caught in that try/catch block.

(Having said that, if doing that will actually start Word if it's not already running, go with the first option and then make sure `oWord` isn't *still* null after the try/catch.)

Comment: The problem here is that you don't handle COM errors other than `MK_E_UNAVAILABLE`. You need to do something about them. Your answer leads towards `null` checks but that's just messy. Especially when there is a very easy way to deal with the issue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Agreed. Your answer is a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

Just assign it a default `null` value:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord = null;
```

This is necessary because the code currently assigns it a value in the `if statement` of the catch {} block, so it's possible that `oWord` never gets a value without the initial/default value.

Comment: I don't think that the scopes are relevant here. The issue is simply that the local variable may not be assigned.

Comment: i am changing my answer to denote the `if` statement.

Comment: What you miss, in my view, as does @Anna, is any handling COM errors other than `MK_E_UNAVAILABLE`. Initializing to `null` just trades a compile time error for a runtime one.

Comment: that wasn't the focus or topic of my (or her) response.  But your point is not wasted.

Comment: I disagree. That's the crux of the question. That this condition is not handled is precisely why the variable is not initialized.

Comment: In your opinion, in my view it's a simple compiler error.  For all you know his catch worked 100% of the time...

Comment: I guess you still don't understand the question if you think it's a compiler error.

Comment: if correcting the compile error by giving it a default value fixes it (like it does) and the code runs successfully after (i have no idea nor do you.. for all we know he's running this on linux) then I'd say the error the OP put up is answered.

Comment: No. You don't understand at all. The variable may still be null after the catch finishes and then you have traded compile time error for runtime error. You do need to address the underlying reason why the compiler correctly complained.

Comment: i get that... i wasn't here trying to solve his application, just explain why the compiler was complaining.. why don't you get that?  lol

Comment: OK. I see. I disagree about using null but that's fine. No worries.